SAP Odata ABAP standard stack calls
I tried to debug the ABAP stack of an OData service, and I see there is this call which is taking more time which is called as "Load MPC class" same with all the DPC and DPC_EXT classes, which is not usual and am trying to understand what exactly this load class do?
Also, where does it load the class and why is it taking a lot of time to load?
Analysis:
I thought it is the first time loading of class tried multiple times to see if it is getting cached or not, interesting question at least for me is, how do we know if an object is cached or not in SAP system?

It depends on the ABAP code executed, so please analyze at your side, there are lots of posts about how to troubleshoot ABAP performance issues.

Loading of the class, is loading the ABAP byte Code into PXA memory on the server. One load might take  more time another another class if there was a swap involved.
Check ST02.
Any evidence of the program buffer being too small ?
If so , request the basis team adjust the size of the buffer.
Note, a small swaps numbers are of little concern. But a large number of program swaps will have a performance impact.

